# problems with python nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

I have problems with python nosetests.
When I try to run the command, I get an import error.
I checked that the module is correctly installed on my machine.
In fact, if I run the interpreter from the directory where I run nosetests,
I am able to import the module.
I checked that the problems are to import not only that module, but different ones.
Where could the fix be?

Here is a possible traceback after I run nosetests:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/user-me/Desktop/bla/tests/blatest1", line 1, in <module>
    import a_module as mo
ImportError: No module named a_module
```

but if I open the python interpreter, I am able to import a_module.

Here is my directory structure:

```
ROOT
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── package1
    └── tests
        ├── tests1
        │   └── package1 -> ../../package1
        └── tests2
```

Comment: Please post a traceback

Comment: whats your directory structure like and the directory you are running nose from?

Comment: package/ contains __init__.py, modules/, tests/, I run from the main package directory.

Comment: What is the "main package directory"? Your stack trace contains paths. Can you tell us from which you run nose?

Comment: @deets: it doesn't matter, from wherever I run nosetests I get the import error. the main package directory in my comment is "package/", what I call "bla" in the previous comment.

Comment: Well, that's the point - you can't invoke nosetests from everywhere, and magically it will know, from where to import packages. You need to run nosetest from the root of your project. Because the "." is in PYTHONPATH by default.

Comment: @deets: when you say the root of my project, do you mean the directory where I have the __init__.py? i.e. the directory where all the other files and directories are contained? if it is so, I get an import error even if I run from such a directory...

Comment: So what happens if you cd into your `ROOT`, and run `nosetests package/tests`?

Comment: I get an error that I am not able to import a module. The module is not inside the package anyway...

Comment: What is this package1 business? do you have a symbolic link to an upward directory?

Comment: yep I have a symbolic link. inside package1 I have some modules. But what I am not able to do is to import another module, the problem is not only with the modules of package1. The import error is in line 1. But if I put before an import to numpy, the problem is not with numpy. The problem will be in line 2 now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very, very weird setup and not likely to be solved by a piecemeal discussion like this. I can only suggest you work from the python tutorial about modules and packages + the very basic and provable working directory-structure I provided - and work yourself into the current setup, verifying each step along - until it breaks. Then you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with nose itself. nose doesn't perform any magic additional to the Python interpreter when looking up modules and packages.

So if we assume a directory structure like this

```
 ROOT
 `-- package
     |-- __init__.py
     `-- tests
         `-- __init__.py
```

and try to do `python -c import package` - when does that work, and when fail?

It's simple. It fails anywhere other than if you invoke the command from within `ROOT`. Nowhere else `package` is known.

The reason is that Python keeps a list of paths (sys.path) which mark roots for packages and modules. A statement `import package` will  be taken, and iterating through all entries in `sys.path` will be searched for either a `package.py`, a `package`-dir with an `__init__.py` in it, or some other cases (C-extensions, new style namespace packages)

So where does `ROOT` get into that list of paths? Simple: the Python interpreter will always add the current working directory to the list of paths.

To sum it up: just call nose from within `ROOT`.

There are additional ways to add a path to the `sys.path`, e.g. by using virtualenvs. Then you can import `package` from everywhere, given you use the venv interpreter.

Comment: sorry I'm not so expert and I probably make confusion, but if I execute the command python -c "import a_module" from my Desktop, it works, while if I run nosetests (which imports a_module as well) from the same position, it doesn't work. Following your advice, I have tried to run nosetests from my root directory / in a way like this: nosetests /.../package/, but I still get the import problem for a_module.

Comment: If you were in the right position, you should run it like `nosetests package/tests` - not reaching around in the directory structure with `..`s - that indicates you are *within* package.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understand that by root directory you mean just the directory one level up to my package. I have tried what you say but same problem...

Comment: my exact structure is as follows: - ROOT
 `-- package
     |-- __init__.py
     `-- tests
         `-- tests1 `-- tests2

Comment: I can run from /tests, but I get the same problem. Also I want to say that the module "a_module" that I'm importing is not inside the package, but it is correctly installed.

Comment: Please provide your exact directory layout, in a form resembling mine, in your question. I used the command `tree` to create that graph, that should help.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to put the structure in a 2-dimensional scheme as you did before. ROOT/
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── tests
        ├── tests1
        └── tests2

Comment: Is it fine like this? Hope so.

Comment: No, it's not - this is all squashed in one line. Why don't you just edit your question to supply it?